# Not able to add comments on Gerrit. It rather gets added as Draft. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: gerrit

Not able to add comments on Gerrit. It rather gets added as Draft. What am I doing wrong? Others in my team are able to add comments though.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Comments are published when you make them part of a review. Post a review and the comments will be published with it. (You can score the commit as +0 if you don't have any opinion either way.)

Comment: Who could know? Gerrit has one of the worst UIs I've seen (especially "feel" part, "look" is merely OK). And that tool creeps thru the industry (press releases would call that "adoption"). Thanks Google!

Comment: How do you "post" a review or "publish" the comments?  I created my first review and added comments to explain my changes, and they all remained as drafts.  Unfortunately I refreshed the page and all the drafts were lost.  +1 about the comment about bad UI!  I much prefer Code Collaborator.

Comment: Go back up to the main review from any file you're looking at (hotkey: `u`) and click the "Review" button, which should be the first one under the patchset.

Comment: @jfritz42 Click the "Reply..." button in the header of the change.

Comment: duskwuff's comment is outdated or at least not applicable to the version of Gerrit I'm using. thSoft's does work.

Comment: You need to click reply in the main header after posting your comment. (hotkey: `u` to get to the main review), this will then let you publish the draft.

Comment: @pfalcon I've never found a Google product with a good UI. Even the simplest thing like the google.com home page has problems. And it gets worse from there.

Answer (score 19):

Click on the Reply button in the header. Then Post it.

Comment: As this is a popular question, I think it would be relevant for you to review [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please add some references and broaden your explanation.

Comment: On the other hand, your answer is fully correct. And I have ran into that myself; so I see some merit. Still, consider improving it!

Comment: `Reply` button to submit a review... so unintuitive.

Comment: @wisbucky For sure.  This is why I hate Gerrit but I have no choice to use it where I'm currently employed.

Answer (score 9):

For those who has happened to be stumbled (like me) with how to post comments for *work-in-progress* (WIP) review without starting review (e.g. leaving in *work-in-progress* state), Gerrit version 2.16. Here's counter-intuitive answer:

- Press "START REVIEW" button - don't afraid, it will not start review immediately (at least on above mentioned version)
- Press "SAVE" (greyish! not quite noticeable) in opened window in left bottom corner

**UPDATE**

In newer version I got 3.2.3 - it's been improved, the button is not greyish and looks normal and in the right bottom corner together with other buttons: | CANCEL | **SAVE** | SEND AND START REVIEW |

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

And since I am not able to add a comment :

When you want to add comments to a specific revision(Patch Set),
switch to that revision and then click on reply. This "Patch Sets" option is found on the upper right corner next to "Download".

[image: screenshot : Switch to a Patch Set]

Had to learn the Hard Way today. :-/

Answer (score 0):

At least on Qt's Gerrit system:

After saving the comment draft, yse the keyboard shortcut 'r' to publish a "review" which publishes the comment.